# How to move image use onFling

Tags: android, onfling

I have a very long picture.

and how can I use the parameter velocityY of onFling to move this picture

This picture will move fast at first, and then move slow down.

like this fling effect: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1sMWF72Cn8&hd=1&t=5

Answer (score 1):

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html